# ¿Por qué "gota serena" es ceguera?

Tags: etimología, historia, locuciones, ciencia, vocabulario-médico

El DLE recoge [**gota serena**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JN4MHke) simplemente como

> 1. f. ceguera.

sin ningún detalle adicional. Rastreando ediciones anteriores he encontrado que aparece ya en el [**Diccionario de Autoridades**](http://web.frl.es/dtSearch/dtisapi6.dll?cmd=getdoc&DocId=23740&Index=C%3A%5Cinetpub%5Cwwwroot%5CDA%5FINDEX&HitCount=1&hits=1%20&SearchForm=%2FDA%5Fform%2Ehtml), con una descripción más amplia:

> GOTA SERENA. Privación total de la vista, sin señal exterior ni lesión sensible en los ojos, que procede de la falta de comunicación de los espíritus visuales, por estar los miembros opticos obstruidos interiormente, o por estar relaxados con el humor que poco a poco o de improviso se embebió en ellos. Latín. *Visûs privatio absque damno oculorum, vel hebetatio*. FRAG. Cirug. Antidotario. Acontece tambien sin causa manifiesta del ojo quitarse la vista: y llámase de los modernos Gota *serena*. [iv.65]

Pero a pesar de la larga explicación no hay una relación evidente entre **gota**, **serena** y **ceguera**. ¿Cuál puede ser el origen?

Adición:

Curiosamente, en [**brasileño**](https://www.significados.com.br/gota-serena/) parece tener el mismo significado:

> Popularmente, gota serena é também uma forma de referir a um tipo de **cegueira** que não deixa lesão no olho, mas provoca a perda total ou parcial da visão (amaurose).

pero también uno totalmente diferente:

> Gota serena (ou gota-serena) é uma expressão popular da região Nordeste do Brasil, cujo significado se refere a um, **impaciência, nervosismo ou exaltação**.

Answer (score 3):

Viene del término medical neolatín *gutta serena*:

> [image]
>
> - [***Vocabulario médico-quirurgico ó diccionario de medicina y cirugia,*** que comprende la etimología y definición de todos los términos usados en estas dos ciencias por los autores antiguos y modernos](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=4FxXCIZdZ9UC&pg=PA51&lpg=PA51&dq=gota+serena), Don Manuel Hurtado de Mendoza (1840)

**'Serena'** significa que el ojo está 'claro/tranquilo' - es que decir que no hay signos visibles de la causa de la ceguera:

> #### gutta serena
>
> 1. former term for blindness of unknown etiology; **the “serena” suggested that the anterior segment of the eye was clear and tranquil, that there was no visible cause for the blindness, no corneal scar, no inflammation, no cataract.** Thus, gutta serena became the code word for blindness due to some unfathomable posterior cause, some damage to retina, optic nerve, or brain.
>
> [*mediLexicon.com*](http://www.medilexicon.com/dictionary/38795)

**'Gota'** viene de la teoría anticuada de los cuatro humores - que una 'gota' de un humor [*mórbido*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Jn8fz2qwjpwC&pg=PA264&lpg=PA264&dq=four+humors+morbid) en la zona afectada era la causa de la enfermedad:

> **Gout.** From *gutta*, a drop. A remnant of the medical theory which attributed all kinds of disorders to the settling of a drop of morbid humour upon the part affected; of which we preserve another instance in the *gutta serena*, or loss of sight without visible affection of the eye. The Sp. has *gota arterica*, or gout, disease of the joints; *gota caduca*, the falling sickness, or epilepsy; Du. *goete*, the palsy.
>
> [*A Dictionary of English Etymology*](http://brittlebooks.library.illinois.edu/brittlebooks_open/Books2010-05/wedghe0001dicofe/wedghe0001dicofev00002/wedghe0001dicofev00002.pdf) (1862)